# Django: use sudo to run server in virtual environment

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, port80

I got Django set up on my server.

I have activated my virtual environment and I'm able to run server successfully on port 8000:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I would like to use port 80 so I'm able to access (test) my app from outside so I use:

```
sudo python manage.py runserver
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
        "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
    ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: You **must not** run things like this with sudo. That is a huge security risk.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
sudo `which python` manage.py runserver
```

inside your virtualenv to run django from sudo.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs if you create the `virtualenv` without the `sudo` command,

`virtualenv` is a separate environment available to the user created,

so if you run `python manage.py runserver` without the `sudo` command it will run properly,

or else `install` `django` will `sudo` right and try `sudo python manage.py runserver`